# Javascript - Adding rows to different tables

Tags: javascript

I have 7 tables (Monday to Sunday) and under each table, is a button to add a new row.
I am not able to rename the id of the table since it is generated from a script.

I think I have 2 options to take

1) Script in javascript to choose table since there are only 7.

2) Encase the table inside Div tags(which I can add) e.g. [this non working example](http://bit.ly/13kiTRi)

Comment: I think you're right :)

Comment: Do all the tables have same id?

Comment: Yes, all have the same id and I can't change them.

Comment: You are going in right direction, just changed your fiddle a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/wYmMk/8/

Comment: Thank you! Right what I needed. Is that your registered nick anyway? :D

Comment: There is a simple problem with my script here, which I just realised. There is also another tag generated between the Div tags I have.
<div>
<form>something here</form>
<table></table>
</div>

Comment: Its not working because of the <form> tag. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: I am still having problems.. How can I push up this post again?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

Call a javascript function on click on button and pass that element. With reference of that element get the corresponding table and add a row in it.

```
function jsfunc(elem) {
     $(elem).prev("table").append("<tr>....</tr>") //add row logic using jquery
}
```

Similar logic using javascript which I think would not be a problem for you to write.
In this case you would never want id of the table.

Comment: @user2008945 - You can always use javascript functions previousSibling, appenChild. In my answer I am not giving a working script but a guidance how he can add a row without reference of id.

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will work**

```
function displayResult(number)
{
    var table1=document.getElementById(number).getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML="New";
    cell2.innerHTML="New";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   YOU can use jQuery for this....

    $('.element').on('click', function(){
             rows='';     
             var row='<tr><td>...</td>....</tr>';
             rows=rows+row;
             $(rows).appendTo('table');
        });

 for jQuery visit...
```

http://jquery.com/

Comment: I always have conflicts with one of my modal plugins when I use jquery. Is there a way to find out where the conflict comes from? =(

Comment: you can take help of jQuery noconflict() method.